# Python memory management and garbage collection

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am currently working on an example to understand Python memory management and garbage collection. In my example, I create a variable (`x = 10`), collect its id, delete it, initiate garbage collector and check if I can still access object in heap by its id (using ctypes).

I think it would return 0 or an error but surprisingly I can still access the object and I don't understand why. Could you help me to understand this case?

A big thank you in advance,

```
import ctypes

x = 10
id_1st_obj = id(x)

del(x)
gc.collect()

print(ctypes.cast(id_1st_obj, ctypes.py_object).value)
```

Comment: Small integers are _interned_ in CPython, the object's never going to be destroyed entirely.

Comment: A big thank you for your comment, could you precise a bit more your answer? Does it means that if I do the same with other object types (str, list, dataframes, ...) then it will work?

Comment: it is very important to understand, `gc.collect` is doing nothing useful here. The main memory management strategy is *reference counting*, which is all that is applicable in the code above. `gc` is the auxiliary garbage collector that only handles reference cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things come into play, but here's a simple counterexample:

```
import ctypes
import gc
x = 1
for _ in range(10):
    x += x
id_1st_obj = id(x)

del x
gc.collect()

print(ctypes.cast(id_1st_obj, ctypes.py_object).value)
```

If you comment `del x`, you get 1024. If you don't, we get some "random" number.

The reason you're seeing the old value is simple - as @jonrsharpe said - small integers (`[-4, 255]`) are *interned*, meaning Python keeps only a single copy of them, and whenever you would reference an integer of that value, it gets pointed at this single copy of the object. So even if you don't have any explicit references to `10` in your code, Python still stores that single copy for interning.

Same might happen with "constant" variables, meaning ones that can be optimised away in the bytecode. That's why even if you change `x = 10` to `x = 1000` in your code you *might* still see the same behaviour (might, as this will not happen for e.g. in interactive session, as the step with optimising constants does not happen there).

Comment: A big thank you for your answer. Very clear. I tried my original code but with 2000 instead of 10 and now it seems to work. thanks